# set light position from script

Tags: scripting, light

I'm trying to render a mesh from script. All good, except the lights. The output rendered mesh is very dark and turning it becomes completely black. How to set them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, you can see all the properties equivalents in Python by hovering over the light properties fields you want to change via Python scripting.

For example,

```
lamp = bpy.data.lamps['Lamp']
lamp.energy = 10  # 10 is the max value for energy
lamp.type = 'POINT'  # in ['POINT', 'SUN', 'SPOT', 'HEMI', 'AREA']
lamp.distance = 100
```

The simpler is to first change their values by hand, before to find the values you need and set them via Python.